# How to check if git repository is already cloned (preferably using jgit)

Tags: git, jgit

I am using **jgit** to programmatically push changes into my git repository.

```
Git git = Git.cloneRepository()
.setURI("https://github.com/eclipse/jgit.git")
.setDirectory("/path/to/repo")
.setCloneAllBranches(true)
.call();
```

However the current syntax tries to clone the repository in the local directory.
I have 2 doubts:

1. Can we programmatically check if the repo is already cloned in local (preferably using jgit api)
2. Can we directly push a file into git hub without cloning the entire repo?

Comment: What is the current syntax?

Comment: You'll get better results if you ask one question per question, please.

Comment: 1) Try to open it and catch the `RepositoryNotFoundException` which tells you that it does not exist. 2) This is possible with a shallow clone. However, JGit does not support shallow clones on the client side. A possibility is to use the GitHub API which lets you commit a file directly.